# Does the safe taxi distance vary behind jet types for light aircraft?

Tags: jet-engine, ground-operations

It would seem a light aircraft taxiing behind a business jet could be closer than a B747. Perhaps there is a law (country or international) regulating power setting of a jet taxiing.

[image]

One authors [recommendations](http://www.flyingstart.ca/FlightTraining/PSTAR/11As.htm).

***Is there any rule of thumb for taxing behind jets based on size or type?***

Comment: FWIW, back in the 1990s on 747-100/200 aircraft, we had no rules insofar as power setting during taxi for the simple reason that we always taxied at idle power with all four engines running. Even then the aircraft would accelerate to greater than the max taxi speed, which was 25 knots at the two 747 carriers I flew for. The only concern about distance from an aircraft in front of you was that the closer you got, the more you'd smell the exhaust. If interested see http://terryliittschwager.com/flying.php#taxiing747 for more info on taxing a 747.

Comment: A 747 behind another 747 isn't probably going to have any issue regardless of power setting. A C-152 behind a 747 is a different issue. What kind of aircraft are you asking about (doing the following)?